# Qt GUI user interaction with QMessageBox from within QThread object

Tags: multithreading, qt, user-interface

I'm using QThread with `MyObject->moveToThread(myThread);` for communication functions that take a while. A few Signals and Slots keep the GUI posted about the progress.

Howeever, some situation may occur during the threaded communication that requires user interaction - since a QMessageBox can't be created inside a thread, I was thinking to emit a signal that would allow me to pause the thread and show the dialog. But first of all, there does not seem to be a way to pause a thread, and second, this attempt probably fails because it requires a way to pass a parameter back to the thread when resuming it.

A differenet approach might be to pass all parameters in question to the thread beforehand, but this may not alway be an option.

How is this usually done?

**Edit**

Thanks for the comment #1 and getting my hopes up, but please elaborate on how to create e.g. a dialog from an object within a thread and how to pause it..

The following example code with Qt 4.8.1 and MSVC++ 2010 results in:

```
MyClass::MyClass created 
MainWindow::MainWindow thread started 
MyClass::start run 
ASSERT failure in QWidget: "Widgets must be created in the GUI thread.", file kernel\qwidget.cpp, line 1299
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "myclass.h"
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QThread *thread = new QThread();
    MyClass* myObject = new MyClass();

    myObject->moveToThread( thread );
    connect(thread,     SIGNAL( started()),     myObject, SLOT(start()));
    connect(myObject,   SIGNAL( finished()),    thread, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(myObject,   SIGNAL( finished()),    myObject, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(thread,     SIGNAL( finished()),    thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    thread->start();
    if( thread->isRunning() )
    {
        qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << "thread started";
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

myclass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
    void finished();

public slots:
    void start();

};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

myclass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"

#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDebug>

MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << "created";
}

void MyClass::start()
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << "run";

    // do stuff ...

    // get information from user (blocking)

    QMessageBox *msgBox = new QMessageBox();
    msgBox->setWindowTitle(      tr("WindowTitle") );
    msgBox->setText(             tr("Text") );
    msgBox->setInformativeText(  tr("InformativeText") );
    msgBox->setStandardButtons(  QMessageBox::Ok | QMessageBox::Cancel);
    msgBox->setDefaultButton(    QMessageBox::Ok);
    msgBox->setEscapeButton(     QMessageBox::Cancel);
    msgBox->setIcon(             QMessageBox::Information);

    int ret = msgBox->exec();

    // continue doing stuff (based on user input) ...

    switch (ret) 
    {
        case QMessageBox::Ok:
            break;

        case QMessageBox::Cancel:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    // do even more stuff

    emit finished();
}
```

Comment: you can pause, pass parameters and create a `QMessageBox` within a `QThread`, what you cannot do is directly call functions on a widget from a secondary thread, please post a sample of your code to better understand what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Should the communication between the main thread and `thread` be implemented with global http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QWaitCondition.html and http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmutex.html objects? So `thread` could emit a signal and wait for data from the GUI thread..

Comment: +1 for not subclassing QThread.

Answer (score 5):

Use Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection in a signal/slot connection (the call to QObject::connect()).

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum

This will block your thread until the slot on the UI thread returns, the slot in the UI thread is then free to display a messagebox/modal dialog/whatever you want to do.

You *must* be sure that your worker thread is actually not on the UI thread, because as the docs say this will cause a dead lock if the signal and slot are on the same thread (since it will block itself).

Comment: +1 I didn't know of BlockingQueuedConnection yet, this in fact seems to solve the issue in a much more comfortable way.

Answer (score 2):

I can't give any specific code right now, but I would do it like this:

1. In `MyClass::start()` lock a `QMutex`.
2. Emit a signal e.g. `messageBoxRequired()`.
3. Wait on a shared `QWaitCondition` on the recent mutex. This will also unlock the mutex while the thread is waiting.
4. In a slot in your MainWindow, e.g. `showMessageBox()`, show the message box.
5. Store the returned value in a member of `MyClass`. You can do this by offering a setter and getter which use the mutex in order to protect the member. Obviously `MyClass` itself should only access that member with those setters/getters itself. (Also see [QMutexLocker](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QMutexLocker.html) for that).
6. Call `wakeOne()` or `wakeAll()` on the shared `QWaitCondition`.
7. The previous `wait()` call will return and `MyClass::start()` will continue execution. If I understand the docs correctly, `QWaitCondition` will lock the mutex again before it returns from `wait()`. This means you have to unlock the mutex directly after the `wait()` call.
8. You can access the message box's return value from your class member (using a thread-safe getter)

Implementations for thread-safe setters/getters would be as follows:

```
void MyClass::setVariable( int value )
{
    QMutexLocker( &_mutex );
    _value = value;
}

int MyClass::getVariable() // Not sure if a 'const' modifier would work here
{
    QMutexLocker( &_mutex );
    return _value;
}
```

Comment: About making the getter const: Using const_cast on mutexes is one of the few valid uses cases for that cast, I think, since locking a mutex is sort of a meta-operation from class data point of view.

Comment: You could make int value atomic with QAtomicInt and avoid need of mutex locking for setter and getter, too.

Comment: @hyde +1 You are right about QAtomicInt. I'll leave the example as-is though, as it can be used for any kind of value, not just int.

Comment: Re: your code comment about the 'const modifier - I've often seen the mutex marked 'mutable' to avoid this issue, not sure if its the right thing to do though.